# how to use javascript in selenium for get data from excel

Tags: java, selenium2

I am using selenium for data entry there are some drop downs in my web page I use `dropDown.selectByVisibleText(input.getCellData(i, 0));`   for every one but after first drop down it is not working because there a javascript call in on change so my next drop down is not display any data. Please give me a better solution.

(I found in my java code, there use a jason array and my selenium may be not able to read comma so when we go to second dropdown value is not found is this possible, if yes please give me a solution)